# is the Arduino shield pinout a standard, so that any Arduino shield can work with any Arduino board

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, pins

I'm new to Arduino and dying to delve in.

There are lots of Arduino base board vendors, and lots of shield vendors.

In general, should I be able to plug any shield into any Arduino board, even with existing shields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not standard - not entirely - although there have been some attempts to make them more standard.

Some things to watch out for:

- SPI

  - The Uno originally had SPI on pins 10-13
  - The Mega had it on another COMMS header instead

SPI has now been standardized to the 6-pin ICSP header, though not all shields honour that, and still use pins 10-13 instead, so they won't work on boards like the Mega

- I2C

  - The Uno has I2C on pins A4/A5
  - The Mega has it on the COMMS header instead

I2C has now been standardized on a special pair of pins added to the end of the digital IO header (pins 8-13 + GND + AREF) though many shields still look for it on pins A4/A5, so they won't work on boards like the Mega

Some other boards, like the Leonardo, also have these (and other) functions on other pins, so may not work with some shields that don't use the SPI / I2C headers.

The basic functions, though, i.e., digital IO and analog inputs and UART 1 are all in the same places on the majority of boards, and most have PWM in the same places too. But you can't rely on any thing more than that between any two boards.

Answer (score 1):

Most shields will fit most of the "regular sized" boards. the obvious exception is the boards like the nano which are tiny. Shields are going to have the best compatibility with the Uno, just because that one is the most common, so if you are going to get one arduino and a bunch of shields, get an uno. Some shields (the gen 1 ethernet and wifi shields in particular had an issue where they could not be used on Megas because the mega listens to SPI on pins 50+ which simply were not connected to the shield, however most of the newer shields will connect to the 6-pin block in the center now-adays to allow Mega usage.

The next thing you want to look at is if you are stacking shields, if they will collide on pin usage (SPI gets around this through multiplexing) and some of the 3.3 volt devices may have conflicts with 5-volt shields. Although the 3.3v devices do provide 5v power-out pins in the same locations as the Uno, it becomes more of an issue with trying to read a 5v on a 3.3v pin, which could damage the microchip.

the best thing to do is to check the documentation of the shields and check which pins they use, what voltages they need/supply, and comparing this with the particular arduino you are using.

Comment: Also a great answer